# display configurable product name underneath the price?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, php-7, php-5.4

is there a way to display configurable product name underneath the price or anywhere?

[image: example to what i mean]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update only for configurable products then,
you can create xml catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml within your theme
that will work only for configurable products
and move page.main.title block after product.info.price

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/>
```

you can also update this as per your theme and needs.